# Displaying country and capital names instead of IDs on Laravel order page

Tags: laravel, foreign-keys, relationship

I have two models: `Wilaya` and `Commune`, basically like `Country` and `Capital`. There is a one-to-many relationship between the two model.

**Wilaya model**

```
class Wilaya extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['nom'];
    use HasFactory;

    public function communes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Commune::class);
    }
}
```

**Commune model**

```
class Commune extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['nom', 'wilaya_id'];
    use HasFactory;

    public function wilaya()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Wilaya::class);
    }
}
```

I want to display the `WilayaName` and `CommuneName` instead of their IDs on my order view page. Here's how I retrieve them in the controller and display them in the view.

```
public function show(Order $order, $id)
{
    $data = Order::find($id);
    //$data = Order::with('wilaya')->find($id);
    $arr = unserialize($data->products);
    //dd($data);

    return view('order.show', compact('data', 'arr'));
}
```

**View**

```
<div class="mb-3">
   <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label">Wilaya: </label>
     <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1"
       aria-describedby="emailHelp" name="email" placeholder="/"
    value="{{ $data->wilaya }}" disabled>
</div>

<div class="mb-3">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label">Ville: </label>
       <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1"
         aria-describedby="emailHelp" name="email" placeholder="/"
    value="{{ $data->commune }}" disabled>
</div>
```

This will only display their `ID` Instead of `Name`.

I tried to fetch the name like this:

`value="{{ $data->commune->name }}"` and `value="{{ $data->wilaya }}"` and

I got an error saying:

> Attempt to read property "name" on int

and I also tried to eager load the relationships on the Controller like this

`$data = Order::with('wilaya.communes')->find($id);`

It throws back an error, saying

> Call to undefined relationship [wilaya] on model [App\Models\Order].**
> knowing there's no relationship between `Order Model`  and `Wilaya model` nor `Commune model`

Feel free to tell me what I have done wrong or what I could have done better. I am new to this,.

Comment: You're starting off the Order class, so can you show the model definition for that? If there's no relationship between Order and Wilaya, then why are you trying to access Wilaya from the Order model?

Comment: sorry I am new to this I didn't understand ? 
on the order it's displaying the ID and I want to display the name based on that ID instead ?

Comment: So the Order has a field `wilaya` that has an ID, correct? If so, you'll need to create a relationship for it. Probably named something other than `wilaya`, considering the field name.

Comment: yeah, but what kind of a relationship will it be ? one 2 one or one 2 many ?

Comment: I would guess one-to-one, since each order would have one wilaya. If you want a reverse relationship, one wilaya would have many orders.

Comment: hmm alright I'll give it a try with one to one relationship

Comment: I have created the relationship but I couldn't dispaly the name

Comment: Can you show what you have now, and what you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

I have figure it out with your help and used one to many relationship

**Order.php**

```
public function wilaya()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Wilaya::class, 'wilaya_id');
}

public function commune()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Commune::class, 'commune_id');
}
```

and inside **Wilaya Model **

```
public function orders()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Order::class);
}
```

and **Commune Model**

```
public function orders()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Order::class);
}
```

Then I called it on the view like this:

```
value="{{ $data->wilaya->nom}}"
value="{{ $data->commune->nom }}"
```

wroks like a charm